# Why cannot I use xterm to see log infos from modules directly but through log files?

Tags: linux, kernel, kernel-module, xterm

I have been reading [linux kernel dev by Love (3 edit)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672329468). I assume, it is quit well known book for kernel development. I have although encounter, I am not able to use code, because I do not know how to compiled in kernel space (e.g. cannot use `<asm/thread_info.h>`). So i have decided to read guide to compile and use kernel modules first (I have also disable secure BIOS in order to load my own modules), here [How Do Modules Get Into Kernel](https://linux.die.net/lkmpg/x44.html#AEN87). I suppose, once I would learn, how to compile kernel space, then would be able to use kernel libraries, thus examples of the book.

Then, from exactly that link (guide), there is mentioned:

```
     It is highly recommended that you type in, compile and load all the examples this guide discusses. It's also highly recommended you do this from a console. 
You should not be working on this stuff in X.

    Modules can't print to the screen like printf() can, but they can log information and warnings, which ends up being printed on your screen, but only on a console. 
If you insmod a module from an xterm, the information and warnings will be logged, but only to your log files. 
You won't see it unless you look through your log files. To have immediate access to this information, do all your work from console.
```

But how can I use console? If i do `echo $TERM`, : `xterm-256color`. So i do have xterm, but I should not have.

Conclusion: There are 2 questions.

1. Should I learn the guide of kernel modules first, in order to use Love's examples?
2. If so, How do I use console instead of xterm then?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_console

Comment: @tink, I can read wiki article, and get to know about history of console, and how did Linus invented it. But that would actually not help me to run from termx, neither does `getty`, because that is not console according to wiki. So this is not enough

Comment: Don't use X ... it was quite clear about that.  Switch to your console. Typically `Ctrl-Alt-F1` ... I would have hoped that someone who wants to do kernel development at least understands the basics of Linux first.

Comment: Kernel doesn't know anything about user space usage, especially X Window or other heavier environments. Kernel operates on system calls and tasks. For kernel all tasks more or less the same.